# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (when doing a background color switcher function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).load(function() {
//Taste the rainbow :)

spectrum();

function spectrum(){
var colorHex = ["#d1ff00", "#ff009c", "#00f0ff", "#707df7", "#ff9000" ];
var colors = colorHex[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorHex.length)];
$('#splash-banner').animate( { backgroundColor: colors }, 4000);
spectrum();
}
});
```

Chrome indicates there is some sort of error with the spectrum function. Looks like there might be an infinite loop going on. Could some one give me some pointers? THANKS

Comment: Man, you call `spectrum()` inside `spectrum()`, unconditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.animate()` isn't blocking, so your `spectrum()` call will execute *immediately* after `spectrum` is executed and the process will start all over.

Pass it in as a callback:

```
$('#splash-banner').animate( { backgroundColor: colors }, 4000, spectrum);
```

You'll run into a stack overflow after about 9000 iterations, but that probably won't be an issue.